# List via loop not being created

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to build a list of urls with a loop and then grab a data point from each url, but it only seems to do it for the last item (MMM) of the list and not all of them... what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc

tickers = ['AAPL','T','MMM']

for i in tickers:
    quote_page = ['https://ycharts.com/companies/'+i+'/dividend_yield']

data = []
for pg in quote_page:
  page = req.get(pg)
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(page)
  divyield = doc.select('.box boxRatio').getElementByText('Average').next.text
  data.append((divyield)[:-1])
print (data)
```

Comment: You just have an indentation problem. Move the block starting at `data = []` one level to the right and then you're good.

Comment: Try `quote_page = ['https://ycharts.com/companies/'+i+'/dividend_yield' for i in tickers]`  Your current version keeps reassigning quote_page and only the last i is kept.

Comment: That's because you are repeatedly overwriting the result of the previous iteration with the result of the current iteration. Assigning to the name `quote_page` doesn't accumulate URLs in a list.

Comment: Have you done any research? In addition to generally being trivial, this exact issue has come up countless times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi @AMC, I did research but I couldn't quite work out the solution for what I'm doing. Sorry.

Comment: I forgot to share this article earlier, you'll probably find it useful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I might have found a few duplicate questions, in the end: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55950586/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50975955/11301900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute

```
for i in tickers:
    quote_page = ['https://ycharts.com/companies/'+i+'/dividend_yield']
```

you make a cycle and in each iteration of the cycle you assign new value (an array of 1 element) to `quote_page` instead of appending new value to array `quote_page`.

You can do:

```
quote_page = []
for i in tickers:
    quote_page.append('https://ycharts.com/companies/'+i+'/dividend_yield')
```

or you can use shorter variant as was suggested by @DarrylG in the comments:

```
quote_page = ['https://ycharts.com/companies/'+i+'/dividend_yield' for i in tickers]
```