# Coding a quiz program where when you get a question wrong the final score decreases, except it doesn't

Tags: python

The way it works is that when you get a question wrong, it sets the variable `score = score - 1`.

```py
a = int(input("How many days are in a year? "))
if a == 365:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    score = score - 1
    print("Incorrect")
```

It runs this code multiple times with a for loop (using different questions each time) but the variable `score` just resets with each loop, meaning the max no. of questions wrong is always 1.

I tried making it `score -= 1` instead but that also didn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can’t diagnose it just from this snippet- provide more relevant code, ideally around the “score” variable

Comment: First, you need to initialize the score, give it an initial value.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing more code, but likely a duplicate of [Python. Variable in while loop not updating.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975955)

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While more code is needed to be sure, you’re probably setting the value of ‘score’ inside your ‘for loop’. You need to initialize score outside of the loop, or else it will be reset to its initial value each time. It would look something like this:

```
score = 100
for i in range(10):
    #your logic
```